# Detect Shared PowerPoint Slide Change Events with Lync SDK

Tags: lync, lync-client-sdk

Using the Lync 2013 Client SDK, is it possible to detect slide change events and their slide number property of shared PowerPoint presentations displayed on the conversation stage?

I've iterated through every shared content property I could find, but haven't seen anything about slide numbers.

I want to use the event and slide number to send a script command to a Microsoft Expression Encoder that is broadcasting a live webcast.  Remote live presenters would then be able to directly control slide changes while presenting.

Any solution suggestions are welcome.  I've also looked into screen scrapping, but whatever control Lync uses on the stage to display slide numbers is detectable by any of the tools I've tried.

Thanks.